# Android Studio не видит DaggerAppComponent

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger2, зависимости, dagger

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

файл `Dagger.kt`:

```
@Component(modules = [AppModule::class])
interface AppComponent {
    val computer: Computer
}

@Module
object AppModule {

    @Provides
    fun provideComputer(
        processor: Processor,
        ram: RAM,
        motherboard: Motherboard
    ) :Computer {
        return Computer(
            processor = processor,
            ram = ram,
            motherboard = motherboard
        )
    }

    @Provides
    fun provideProcessor(): Processor {
        return Processor()
    }

    @Provides
    fun provideRam(): RAM {
        return RAM()
    }

    @Provides
    fun provideMotherboard(): Motherboard {
        return Motherboard()
    }

}
```

зависимости, которые добавлял, чтобы решить эту проблему:

```
    dependencies {

...
    
        def daggerVer = 2.27 // or latest version
    
        implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger:$daggerVer"
        implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:$daggerVer"
        kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:$daggerVer"
        kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$daggerVer"
    
        implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.35.1'
        implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android:2.35.1'
        kapt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.35.1'
        kapt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:2.35.1'
    
        kapt  "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:2.12"
    
    }
```

Также пробовал:

```
Build -> Rebuild Project
```

Выходить из `Android Studio`
Удалять папку `build` в `app`
Запускать `Android Studio` снова

добавлял

```
kapt.use.worker.api=false
kapt.incremental.apt=false
```

в `gradle.properties`

структура:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А вы подключили плагин kapt (так же и там же где плагин application подключён)?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, внутри `gradle(Module)` плагин `id 'kotlin-kapt'` подклчён

Comment: Странно. А при сборке никаких ошибок нет?

Comment: @ЮрийСПбб в разделе `build` `Android Studio` пишет `'kapt.use.worker.api' is deprecated and scheduled to be removed in Kotlin 1.8 release.` и `Your project has set android.useAndroidX=true, but configuration :app:_agp_internal_javaPreCompileDebug_kaptClasspath still contains legacy support libraries, which may cause runtime issues.
This behavior will not be allowed in Android Gradle plugin 8.0.`, но сборка проходит успешно

Comment: Это не похоже на проблему. Меня смущает, что вы в некой main функции пытаетесь что-то с Dagger делать. По идее делать это надо в Application классе. Ещё я вижу у вас val в компоненте. Попробуйте его на fun заменить. Возможно из-за этого не может сгенерить класс. Возможно в логах даже это где-то есть.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, изучаю Dagger по видео уроку, поэтому делаю как там (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1dOsef2ZzQ8), на `fun` поменял, выполнил `Rebuild Project`, не помогло

Comment: У меня только одна идея осталась - у вас дублируются зависимости Dagger. Попробуйте только одну какую-то версию оставить. А, ещё может быть в версии котлина быть дело - какая у вас?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, избавление от лишних зависимостей не помогло

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, не уверен, что смотрю правильно, но `Current Kotlin plugin version: 212-1.7.10-release-333-AS5457.46`, `id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.7.10' apply false`

Comment: Кажется, вот и проблема - вы, кажется, плагин котлина явно отключили. Попробуйте убрать `apply false`

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, заработало и без этого, но я пока что не понял, после каких конкретно моих действий это произошло, когда пойму, напишу, в любом случае, спасибо